# Syntax Error in Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, syntax

My text editor is telling me I have a syntax error in my Javascript.  It is somewhere in this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> if (!window.mstag) mstag = {loadTag : function(){},time : (new Date()).getTime()};</script>
```

Jslint tells me that I have an "Unexpected '<'." in Line 1, Character 1.  So that, I'm guessing, means I have an error in the script type itself, which doesn't make much sense to me.  I'm a newb, sorry if this is a super-basic question.  Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: There is no syntax error. What editor tells you there is one?

Answer (score 6):

JSLint validates *javascript*. What you have here is a HTML `<script>`tag with javascript inside. You should **only** paste in the *javascript* to JSLint:

```
if (!window.mstag) mstag = {loadTag : function(){},time : (new Date()).getTime()};
```

My guess is that you've use `<script type="text/javascript">` inside a `.js` file and your editor has no idea what is going on - is that correct?

Comment: Ok, thank you!  I still have errors, but I will dig in further!

Comment: @Anne If it's because it's in a separate `.js` file you should not use any `<script>` tags. They're only used when outputting HTML.

Comment: This is actually a snippet for Hubspot that isn't working correctly.  I was just hoping there would be some small but noticeable error in the coding...it looks like it might be a bigger problem.